# Quickblox group chat message listener doesn't work

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have integrated my app with Quickblox and I registered the group chat global listener after session has created as follow.

register GroupChatManagerListener after session created.

```
if (groupChatManager != null) {
    groupChatManager.addGroupChatManagerListener(this);
}
```

and in the GroupChatManagerListener I have the following code.

```
@Override
public void chatCreated(QBGroupChat qbGroupChat) {
    qbGroupChat.addMessageListener(mQBGroupChatMessageListener);
    qbGroupChat.addMessageSentListener(mQBMessageSentListener);
}
```

I put the log, and it seems like the chatCreated never been called. Could anyone tell me what could be the possible reasons that this doesn't work or any suggestion to listen the group message globally.

Note: I implement exactly the same for private chat, and it works fine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Bump this issue. Faced with the same problem

Comment: To be honest, there is no solution for this yet, but there is a workaround that you can try now. When any user goes to the chat screen, you can send out they system message to all other users in the group, then the other side will just receive the system message and register listener with that dialog.

Comment: did you find any solution rather than the workaround you mentioned above

Comment: @Pallavi, I think the issue was solved in version 3.0, and now I am using the latest version of the sdk which is 3.3.1, and I am not using that workaround anymore.